# Alternate series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

The  alternate series $S=\displaystyle \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}+(-1)^n}  $ converges?

$S$ is absolutely convergent?

Comment: sorry to ask this, but what is the idea behind converging? I am hearing a lot on this site..

Comment: have you done any work here?

Comment: @Sid Converging is when a series, function, etc. gets closer to a specific value. Like how 0.9, 0.99, 0.999... gets closer to 1.

Comment: y tried using leibniz rule but not works $a_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt(n)+(-1)^n}$ is not a monotonic sequence and not converges to 0 
and I don't know calculate $\lim an$

Comment: So in this question, S is getting or will get closer to 1? (a specific arbitrary value)

Comment: @Sid No, that was just meant to be an example. In this specific question, $S$ doesn't get closer to a specific number so it's not convergent (it is divergent).

Answer (score 7):

We have using Taylor series

$$ \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}+(-1)^n}=\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt n}\left(1+\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt n}\right)^{-1}=\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt n}-\frac1n+\mathcal O\left(\frac1{n^{3/2}}\right)$$
so we see that the given series is the sum of $3$ series: two convergent series using  Leibniz theorem and using the comparison with a Riemann series and a  harmonic series which is divergent. Hence the given series is divergent.